# Call method on selecting an option

Tags: angularjs

I want to call specific methods based on which option was clicked, like this:

```
<select>
   <option value="0" ng-click="callMethodOne()">1</option>
   <option value="1" ng-click="callMethodTwo()">2</option>
</select>
```

But it doesn't work, I can't call `ng-click` inside the option tag.

I also can't use it inside the select tag because I won't be able to call the function by its name.

How could I solve this?

Comment: Do you have a controller defined which contains callMethodOne() & callMethodTwo() ?

Comment: Check this out already answered similar to what you have asked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519805/how-to-use-ng-click-on-ng-option-or-other-way-to-assign-value)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `ng-change` config along with `ng-model` on `<select>` tag.

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="onChange">
   <option value="0">1</option>
   <option value="1">2</option>
</select>
```

Now, In your controller, define onChange function as

```
$scope.onChange = function(){
 // The option selected is stored in $scope.selectedOption
 // perform the business logic using $scope.selectedOption
}
```