# Ng-Click in Select drop down options

Tags: angularjs

Is that possible to use ng-click in select options?
I have read other threads and everyone asked or suggested with a same controller functions.
I want to trigger different functions on different select options.
OR alternatively can i use button in select options?

```
<select>
  <option ng-click="NextWeek()" value="">Select Branches</option>
  <option ng-click="next15Days()">Select Branches</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ng-click on ng-option( or other way to assign value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519805/how-to-use-ng-click-on-ng-option-or-other-way-to-assign-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work for you using `ng-model` and `ng-change`. Below is your html code. updateSelected method will be called whenever the select option is changed.

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-change="updateSelected()">
  <option value="nextweek">Select Branches</option>
  <option value="next15days">Select Branches</option>
</select>
```

This is you controller code. The scope variable `selectedOption` contains the value of the selected dropdown option.

```
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('selectCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.updateSelected = function(){
    switch($scope.selectedOption){
      case "nextweek":
        $scope.NextWeek();
        break;
      case "next15days":
        $scope.next15Days();
        break;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man! It works. I still am little confused that why we cannot use ng-click in Select-options?